# Issue with Subquery in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Select query:

```
Select  left([Foundation_Account_Name],4)
     From [dbo].[tbl_Foundation_Account]    
        Where [Foundation_Account_Name]
```

That returns

```
MAZA
SUMI
APLH
```

I have a second Select query that selects the same fields from a temp table

```
Select left([Foundation Account Name],4) 
            From [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO]
                 Where [Foundation Account Name] IS NOT NULL))
```

That returns

```
SUMI
```

I want to use these select queries in a where clause that will return just `SUMI` when I run the select on the `tbl_Foundation_Account`. My idea was this,

```
Select  left([Foundation_Account_Name],4)
     From [dbo].[tbl_Foundation_Account]    
        Where [Foundation_Account_Name] = (Select  left([Foundation_Account_Name],4)
     From [dbo].[tbl_Foundation_Account]    
        Where [Foundation_Account_Name] = (Select left([Foundation Account Name],4) 
            From [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO]
                 Where [Foundation Account Name] IS NOT NULL))
```

In theory (At least in my head anyway) the main select query is only going to select records from `tbl_Foundation_Account` where the second and third select query equally each other, which should be `SUMI`. Right now this just returns nothing, and the deeper down the rabbit hole I get, the most confused I'm making myself. Is this query that messed up, or am I close to achieving my desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `intersect` to get the common results from both the queries.

```
Select left([Foundation_Account_Name],4)
From [dbo].[tbl_Foundation_Account]    
INTERSECT 
Select left([Foundation Account Name],4) 
From [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO]
Where [Foundation Account Name] IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Just building on what you have already... and JOINING the tables together...
though intersect seems cleaner...

```
with A as (SELECT left([Foundation_Account_Name],4) ID
           FROM [dbo].[tbl_Foundation_Account]), 
     b as (SELECT left([Foundation Account Name],4) ID
           FROM [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO])

SELECT C.left([Foundation_Account_Name],4) 
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Foundation_Account]  C
INNER JOIN A on A.ID = C.left([Foundation_Account_Name],4)
INNER JOIN B on A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: Why do you need the Table b? Wouldn't your query work perfectly by removing everythign that relates to it?

Comment: I think you mean why do I need A.  A is the same as c.  and you're right I really don't need A nor A intersect B join.  I wasn't looking at the table names  I assumed all 3 were different.

Comment: I totally meant b because you need to keep the `INNER JOIN A on A.ID = C.left([Foundation_Account_Name],4)` line, and apart from that A and b are the same.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want to do is something along the lines of :

```
SELECT {{FIELDS TO QUERY}}
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Foundation_Account] fa    
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO] rdo
    WHERE left(rbo.[Foundation Account Name],4) = left(fa.[Foundation Account Name],4)
)
```

Alternatively, you could also simply join your tables if you need to access any data from `Import_tbl_RDO` :

```
SELECT {{FIELDS TO QUERY}}
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Foundation_Account] fa    
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO] rdo
    ON left(rbo.[Foundation Account Name],4) = left(fa.[Foundation Account Name],4)
```

The "disadvantage" of this second method is that if you have multiple `Import_tbl_RDO` rows that fit the criteria, you will end up with duplicate rows (which may or may not be wanted).

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense exactly as posed, for if the result you really want is whatever the query on the temp table returns, then why would you not just use that directly?

I suppose what you're really after is to filter the results of a query returning more columns based on the results of your query against the temp table.  If the temp table query is guaranteed to return exactly one row every time, then you could write that like so:

```
Select 
  -- column1, column2, ...
From [dbo].[tbl_Foundation_Account]    
Where left([Foundation Account Name],4) = (
    Select left([Foundation Account Name],4) 
    From [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO]
    Where [Foundation Account Name] IS NOT NULL
  )
```

More likely, though, the temp-table query can return multiple rows, or perhaps none, under some circumstances.  In that case, you probably want an `IN` condition:

```
Select 
  -- column1, column2, ...
From [dbo].[tbl_Foundation_Account]    
Where left([Foundation Account Name],4) IN (
    Select left([Foundation Account Name],4) 
    From [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO]
    Where [Foundation Account Name] IS NOT NULL
  )
```